# Newton's method: Is the change of parameter values between consecutive steps always decreasing?

Tags: convergence-divergence, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Assume that I have a twice differentiable function  $f(x)$ which I try to maximize with respect to $x$ (let's say $x$ is $k$-dimensional vector). When performing optimization via Newton algorithm, assuming that the sequence of guesses $x_0, x_1, ... , x_n$ converges to correct value $\hat x$ does the following hold:

$||x_{p+1}-x_p|| \leq ||x_p - x_{p-1}||$,

where $0 \leq p \leq n $. What I am actually after is that can I use the above property (if it really holds like I assume it does) for checking if my algorithm is diverging i.e. if the my parameter estimate changes more than in the previous step, I might be overshooting and I backtrack so the previous condition holds.

Comment: Such an inequality might hold for sufficiently large $p$, but there's no reason to expect it to hold for *all* $p$.

Comment: Explicit counterexample: Take $f(x)=-x^2-x^{100}$, $x_0=0.95$. Then $x_1\approx0.912$, $x_2\approx0.344$.